# Flask-OAuthlib "TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'str'"

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, flask

I am using Flask-OAuthlib to setup an OAuth2 server. When I access the server via the client.py script I get an error:

```
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'str'
```

Apparently, something seems to be wrong with the resp variable and printing it results in "Invalid response from remote", which isn't very helpful.

Here is the relevant portion of [my client code](https://github.com/lepture/example-oauth2-server/blob/master/client.py):

```
@app.route('/authorized')
@remote.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )

    session['remote_oauth'] = (resp['access_token'], '') # error occurs here
    return jsonify(oauth_token=resp['access_token']) # and here
```

I realize there's an open issue (2 actually, for the same issue) but the author is "on vacation"....who knows for how long

Comment: Have you tried whacking a pdb in before you set session var and checking what rest actually contains.  I suspect it's not a dict like you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response in this case is an flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthException(RuntimeError) and not the dict you would get if the token request was successful. The error message could certainly be more helpful and I'm sure a pull request would be accepted ([good starting point](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/flask_oauthlib/client.py#L602)).

I've not tried to replicate this with a flask-oauthlib provider and just did a quick test against Google using your example code but the cause is likely the same in both cases. flask-oauthlib.client assumes the token retrieval is a GET request when both flask-oauthlib and Google assumes a POST by default.

Try adding `access_token_method='POST'` to your remote_app invocation

```
remote = oauth.remote_app(
    ...
    authorize_url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/authorize',
    access_token_method='POST'
)
```

and see if that helps.